# Page to show "Modified By" and "Last Modified Date" of file in file library

Tags: document-library, jquery, jquery-ajax

I have a .csv file in a file library, i would like to know if is there way to display in some page when the .csv file was last modified, and who did.

Does anybody know any code in to get this information using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code that can be added to a page in script editor web part. Assuming the ID of the csv file in the library is known. Otherwise you need to adjust the camlquery. Please modify it to store the `modified by` and `last modified date` values to holders/containers.

```
var siteUrl = '/';

function retrieveListItems() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('library_title');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + 
        '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>');
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(collListItem);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
                                    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));        

}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

    var listItemInfo = '';

    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() + 
            '\nModified By: ' + oListItem.get_item('Editor').get_lookupValue()+
            '\nLast Modified Date: ' + oListItem.get_item('Modified').format('dd/MM/yyyy, hh:ss');
    }

    console.log(listItemInfo.toString());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

and the output is

```
ID: 1
Modified By: Ahmad Zia
Last Modified Date: 19/08/2014, 08:47
```